# Received email but it's not in my SE inbox

Tags: support, email, global-inbox

Today I received an email message from do-not-reply@stackexchange.com, that says "The following items were added to your inbox". The message contains part of a question from someone who read one of my posts. But when I login and check my inbox at SE, there are no new messages. How can I answer the question?

Comment: It was probably a comment, that got deleted.